# SQL Server Data Volumes on SSD Storage

Tags: sql-server

With traditional storage it has been a best practice to multi-thread SQL data volumes using mount points.  With the advent of all flash arrays, is there any changes with Microsoft best practices on this?  Possibly to consolidate into one large volume or is OS queuing, etc still going to really be the bottleneck to stay with mount points?

Comment: I don't know if Microsoft has said anything explicitly about it on TechNet but I found http://sqlmag.com/storage/using-solid-state-disks-sql-server-storage-solutions quite interesting